# Can I install android app in windows 11 from android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-11

As new windows 11 has android app support, and you can install your favorite app from google playstore to windows 11. I'm wondering if I can install my app directly from the android studio through ADB.

Comment: Correction: You can't install apps from the Google Playstore. The only officially supported Android store on Windows 11 is the Amazon App Store.

Comment: I think it's possible to install Google Playstore in windows 11, a lot of articles are available for that @AlexanderHoffmann .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can , follow [this](https://allthings.how/how-to-install-and-run-android-apps-on-a-windows-11-pc/) on how to use apk on windows .

Then you build the apk using android studio or gradle build , and locate the apk and run as described.

Comment: their no instruction for installing apk directly from android studio. but other information was helpful so, I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: @subratasharma The article mentions to connect with `adb` to the local machine. Does Windows 11 Android subsystem appear as a connected Android Device inside Android Studio once the connection has been made?

Comment: The article link given by George indeed is no nonsense walk through, though it is bit long with many steps it just works. If you are in widows 10 home edition, you can enable hyper-v follow the steps at [link] (https://www.itechtics.com/enable-hyper-v-windows-10-home/) hyper-v. @Ale

Answer (score 1):

The article link given by George indeed is no nonsense walk through, though it is bit long with many steps it just works. If you are in widows 10 home edition, you can enable hyper-v by following the steps at [hyper-v on windows home edition](https://www.itechtics.com/enable-hyper-v-windows-10-home/) .

After connecting with adb it does appear as a device in android studio.

#adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:58526

[image: Hyper-V on Windows home edition]